# How to use ->where() condition on Route Params in Laravel

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes

I have changed the default parameter of Route in **Laravel 5.7** as

```
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionController')->parameters(['questions' => 'question_slug']);
```

But I'm confuesed how I set regex pattern to that new parameter, I want to apply `slug_regex` on this parameter, I tried this:

```
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionController')->parameters(['questions' => 'question_slug'])->where(['slug' => '^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$']);
```

But getting this error:

> **BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::where does not exist.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found solution in one line of code, **to set regex validation** on parameter/parameters just navigate to `YourProjectName\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` where you will find the method named as `boot`, it contains this code by default;

```
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();
}
```

Just add your parameter here as;

`Route::pattern('parameter', 'regex-rule-here');`

So your code will be as;

```
public function boot()
{
    //

    Route::pattern('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');

    parent::boot();
}
```

For more parameters simply pass your parameters in an array as:

`Route::pattern(['1st-para' => 'regex-rule-here', '2nd-para' => 'regex-rule-here']);`

Answer (score 0):

So `Route` isn't a real class in Laravel and is in fact a [Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades) which gives you static like access to real classes.

The real class that this gives you access to is `Illuminate\Routing\Router` when looking at the `resource()` function (this is what is called when you write `Route::resource()`) we can see that it returns an `Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration` object and the `where()` method isn't available on this class.

So how to solve your problem? Well there's two ways, you could check the `slug` is valid in your `controller` actions, or you could create a `middleware` as resource routes can have `middleware` attached.